# Why MagSetImageScalingCallback function fails when is executed in new desktop?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, magnification-api

I'm trying get a screenshot of a new desktop created ([`CreateDesktop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms682124(v=vs.85).aspx) api + executing **explorer.exe** to new desktop) using **Magnification** api like showed in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607288/Screenshot-using-the-Magnification-library) tutorial. I ported with success the C++ code from tutorial to Delphi and both examples (C++ and Delphi) works fine when executed from *Win Vista* ~ *Win 10* and with [Aero Theme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) enabled.

The trouble to this question is because if i create a new desktop (clone original desktop) and execute this example of screen capture, [`MagSetImageScalingCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) fails.

Someone know a possible solution to *MagSetImageScalingCallback* also work on new desktop created?

Thanks in advance by any help.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CAPTURE: TButton;
    SaveFileDialog1: TSaveDialog;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CAPTUREClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Magnification;

{$R *.dfm}

function HostWndProc(hWindow: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: wParam; lParam: lParam)
  : LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  Result := DefWindowProc(hWindow, Msg, wParam, lParam);
end;

var
  MyBMP: TBitmap;
  abitmap: HBitmap;
  desktoprect: TRect;
  hWndMag: HWND;
  CallbackDone: Boolean = False;

function MagImageScalingCallback(HWND: HWND; srcdata: Pointer;
  srcheader: MAGIMAGEHEADER; destdata: Pointer; destheader: MAGIMAGEHEADER;
  unclipped: TRect; clipped: TRect; dirty: HRGN): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  lpbmih: TBitmapInfoHeader;
  lpbmi: TBitmapInfo;
  aDC: HDC;
begin

  aDC := GetWindowDC(HWND);

  Fillchar(lpbmih, sizeof(lpbmih), 0);
  lpbmih.biSize := sizeof(lpbmih);
                 // (-) Otherwise the image is upside down.
  lpbmih.biHeight := -srcheader.height { -GetDeviceCaps(aDC, VERTRES) };
  lpbmih.biWidth := srcheader.width { GetDeviceCaps(aDC, HORZRES) };
  lpbmih.biSizeImage := srcheader.cbSize;
  lpbmih.biPlanes := 1;
  lpbmih.biBitCount := 32;
  lpbmih.biCompression := BI_RGB;

  Fillchar(lpbmi, sizeof(lpbmi), 0);
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biSize := sizeof(lpbmi.bmiHeader);
                          // (-) Otherwise the image is upside down.
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biHeight := -srcheader.height { -GetDeviceCaps(aDC, VERTRES) };
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biWidth := srcheader.width { GetDeviceCaps(aDC, HORZRES) };
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage := srcheader.cbSize;
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes := 1;
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount := 32;
  lpbmi.bmiHeader.biCompression := BI_RGB;

  MyBMP := TBitmap.Create;
  abitmap := 0;
  try
    abitmap := CreateDIBitmap(aDC, lpbmih, CBM_INIT, srcdata, lpbmi,
      DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    MyBMP.handle := abitmap;
    MyBMP.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

    CallbackDone := True;

  finally
    DeleteDC(aDC);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.CAPTUREClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  filterList: THWNDArray;
  sourceRect: TRect;
begin
  filterList[0] := Form1.handle;

  If (MagSetWindowFilterList(hWndMag, MW_FILTERMODE_EXCLUDE, 1,
    @filterList[0])) Then
  begin

    sourceRect.left := 0;
    sourceRect.top := 0;
    sourceRect.right := desktoprect.width;
    sourceRect.bottom := desktoprect.height;

    CallbackDone := False;

    If (MagSetWindowSource(hWndMag, sourceRect)) Then
      Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;

    repeat

    until CallbackDone;

    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;

    SaveFileDialog1.Title := 'Save Image File';
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter :=
      'JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif|Png Image|*.png';
    SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt := 'bmp';
    SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex := 2;
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;

    if SaveFileDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      MyBMP.SaveToFile(SaveFileDialog1.FileName);
      MessageDlg('File saved: ' + SaveFileDialog1.FileName, mtInformation,
        [mbOK], 0);
    end
    else
      MessageDlg('Save file was cancelled', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);

    DeleteObject(abitmap);
    MyBMP.Free;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if (MagUninitialize) then
    MessageDlg('Magnification api finished!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  HOST_CLASSNAME = 'MagnifierHost';
var
  wc: TWndClass;
  hWndHost, desktop: HWND;
begin

  hWndHost := 0;

  wc.lpszClassName := HOST_CLASSNAME;
  wc.lpfnWndProc := @HostWndProc;
  wc.Style := 0;
  wc.hInstance := 0;
  wc.hIcon := 0;
  wc.hCursor := 0;
  wc.hbrBackground := 0;
  wc.lpszMenuName := nil;
  wc.cbClsExtra := 0;
  wc.cbWndExtra := 0;

  desktop := GetDesktopWindow;
  GetWindowRect(desktop, desktoprect);

  if (Winapi.Windows.RegisterClass(wc) <> 0) then

    hWndHost := CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST Or WS_EX_LAYERED Or
      WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, HOST_CLASSNAME, 'Host Window',
      WS_POPUP Or WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 0, 0, desktoprect.width, desktoprect.height,
      0, 0, hInstance, nil);

  if (hWndHost <> 0) then
  begin
    SetWindowPos(hWndHost, 0, 0, 0, desktoprect.width, desktoprect.height,
      SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWndHost, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);
  end;

  If (MagInitialize) Then
    hWndMag := CreateWindowEx(0, WC_MAGNIFIER, 'MagnifierWindow',
      WS_CHILD Or MS_SHOWMAGNIFIEDCURSOR Or WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, desktoprect.width,
      desktoprect.height, hWndHost, 0, 0, nil);

  If (hWndMag = 0) Then
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));

  if (MagSetImageScalingCallback(hWndMag, MagImageScalingCallback)) then
    ShowMessage('MagSetImageScalingCallback registred!');

  ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));

  left := (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - width) div 2;
  top := (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - height) div 2;
end;

end.
```

Magnification.pas

```
unit Magnification;

{$ALIGN ON}
{$MINENUMSIZE 4}

interface

uses
  Windows;

const
  // Magnifier Class Name
  WC_MAGNIFIERA: AnsiString = 'Magnifier';
  WC_MAGNIFIERW: WideString = 'Magnifier';
  WC_MAGNIFIER = 'Magnifier';

  // Magnifier Window Styles
  MS_SHOWMAGNIFIEDCURSOR = $0001;
  MS_CLIPAROUNDCURSOR = $0002;
  MS_INVERTCOLORS = $0004;

  // Filter Modes
  MW_FILTERMODE_EXCLUDE = 0;
  MW_FILTERMODE_INCLUDE = 1;

type
  tagMAGTRANSFORM = record
    v: array[1..3, 1..3] of Single;
  end;
  MAGTRANSFORM = tagMAGTRANSFORM;
  TMagTransform = tagMAGTRANSFORM;
  PMagTransform = ^TMagTransform;

  tagMAGIMAGEHEADER = record
    width: UINT;
    height: UINT;
    format: TGUID;
    stride: UINT;
    offset: UINT;
    cbSize: UINT;
  end;
  MAGIMAGEHEADER = tagMAGIMAGEHEADER;
  TMagImageHeader = tagMAGIMAGEHEADER;
  PMagImageHeader = ^TMagImageHeader;

  tagMAGCOLOREFFECT = record
    transform: array[1..5, 1..5] of Single;
  end;
  MAGCOLOREFFECT = tagMAGCOLOREFFECT;
  TMagColorEffect = tagMAGCOLOREFFECT;
  PMagColorEffect = ^TMagColorEffect;

  TMagImageScalingCallback = function (hwnd: HWND; srcdata: Pointer;
    srcheader: MAGIMAGEHEADER; destdata: Pointer; destheader: MAGIMAGEHEADER;
    unclipped: TRect; clipped: TRect; dirty: HRGN): BOOL; stdcall;

  THWNDArray = array[0..0] of HWND;
  PHWNDArray = ^THWNDArray;

  // Public Functions
  function MagInitialize(): BOOL; stdcall;
  function MagUninitialize(): BOOL; stdcall;

  function MagSetWindowSource(hwnd: HWND; rect: TRect): BOOL; stdcall;
  function MagGetWindowSource(hwnd: HWND; var Rect: TRect): BOOL; stdcall;
  function MagSetWindowTransform(hwnd: HWND; var Transform: TMagTransform): BOOL; stdcall;
  function MagGetWindowTransform(hwnd: HWND; var Transform: TMagTransform): BOOL; stdcall;
  function MagSetWindowFilterList(hwnd: HWND; dwFilterMode: DWORD;
    count: Integer; pHWND: PHWNDArray): BOOL; stdcall;
  function MagGetWindowFilterList(hwnd: HWND; var dwFilterMode: DWORD;
    count: Integer; pHWND: PHWNDArray): Integer; stdcall;
  function MagSetImageScalingCallback(hwnd: HWND;
    MagImageScalingCallback: TMagImageScalingCallback): BOOL; stdcall;
//  MagImageScalingCallback WINAPI MagGetImageScalingCallback(HWND hwnd );
  function MagSetColorEffect(hwnd: HWND; var Effect: TMagColorEffect): BOOL; stdcall;
  function MagGetColorEffect(hwnd: HWND; var Effect: TMagColorEffect): BOOL; stdcall;

implementation

const
  MagnificationDll = 'Magnification.dll';

  function MagInitialize; external MagnificationDll name 'MagInitialize';
  function MagUninitialize; external MagnificationDll name 'MagUninitialize';
  function MagSetWindowSource; external MagnificationDll name 'MagSetWindowSource';
  function MagGetWindowSource; external MagnificationDll name 'MagGetWindowSource';
  function MagSetWindowTransform; external MagnificationDll name 'MagSetWindowTransform';
  function MagGetWindowTransform; external MagnificationDll name 'MagGetWindowTransform';
  function MagSetWindowFilterList; external MagnificationDll name 'MagSetWindowFilterList';
  function MagGetWindowFilterList; external MagnificationDll name 'MagGetWindowFilterList';
  function MagSetImageScalingCallback; external MagnificationDll name 'MagSetImageScalingCallback';
  function MagSetColorEffect; external MagnificationDll name 'MagSetColorEffect';
  function MagGetColorEffect; external MagnificationDll name 'MagGetColorEffect';

end.
```

---

**EDITION:**

> `GetLastError()` returns **50** - **ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED** - *The request is not supported.*

But this works on original desktop, i not understood.

Comment: I don't see any error checking

Comment: You have a line of code that displays the last error.. why not state exactly what it is? Also, which OS's is it failing on? Note that the call has been deprecated in Win7 and later, so I wouldn't rely on it working.

Comment: Don't give such crucial details in comments. Make it part of the question. Further, remove all the unnecessary code. Make a [mcve]. Also, "The MagSetImageScalingCallback function is deprecated in Windows 7 and later, and should not be used in new applications. There is no alternate functionality." that's pretty decisive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, but if new desktop have the same characteristics of original desktop this should work.

Comment: You still have not indicated which OS's it "fails" on. Also, whether or not they're 32 bit or 64 bit, and whether or not your app is. See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692162(v=vs.85).aspx, which states: "Note  The Magnification API is not supported under WOW64; that is, a 32-bit magnifier application will not run correctly on 64-bit Windows."

Comment: @DaveNottage, the `MagSetImageScalingCallback` function worked fine on original desktop and fails on new desktop with error showed in my edition above (the code was tested on Win 7 Ultimate x64).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

This is working on *Win 8/8.1* and *10*, all x86 and x64.

Not works in Windows versions < *8*